# Setting a static class property dynamically with squiqlies

Tags: php, static-members

I know I can do this:

```
class Foo {
   public function bar( $k, $v ){
       $this->{$k} = $v;
   }
}
```

If I try to do:

```
class Foo {
    public static function bar( $k, $v ){
       self::${$k} = $v;
    }
}
```

It does not work.  I probably don't understand static properties enough.  Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set dynamically a static property (otherwise wasn't static :P), but you can manage it, example

```
class Foo {
    static $vars;
    public static function set( $k, $v ){
        self::$vars[$k] = $v;
    }
    public static function get( $k ){
        return isset(self::$vars[$k]) ? self::$vars[$k] : 'error';
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you confuse const with static. The static property does not prohibit dynamically setting it. It only means that the property is shared by all instances of the class.

Answer (score 1):

As of PHP 5.1.0 you can use the [ReflectionClass](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.setstaticpropertyvalue.php) if the properties are predefined but you want to assign new values dynamically.

```
class Foo {
    public static $prop1; 

    public static function bar( $k, $v ){
       $class = new ReflectionClass("Foo");
       $class->setStaticPropertyValue($k, $v);
    }
}

$k = 'prop1';
$v = 'test';
Foo:bar($k, $v);
```

**Disclaimer:** Using reflection produces hard to read code and is potentially exploitable. It also makes it hard to refactor code at later times. So check if your problem can not be solved in a different way first.